# Would it be correct/ellegant use only alloc without init?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, init

If we don't want to implement init method in our class, and bearing in mind that init in NSObject only returns an instance of the object without initialization, I don't see the point of calling init if we already get the instance with alloc. I have tried and it works, but I am not sure it won't cause future problems.

```
myClass *newObject = [myClass alloc];
```

instead of:

```
myClass *newObject = [[myClass alloc] init];
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, just calling `alloc` would not be correct. `alloc` zeroes out all instance variables of the object, `init` then has the chance to set all or some instance variables to their default values. Some classes even use their `init` methods to create another instance and return that one instead of the one you allocated.

Many classes expect that their `init` methods get called and would possibly cause crashes if you don't call `init`. If you are talking about a custom class that inherits directly from `NSObject` and needs no initialization of instance variables, you might get away with `[myClass alloc]` but it is definitely not good programming style.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. "If you are talking about a custom class that inherits directly from NSObject and needs no initialization of instance variables, you might get away with [myClass alloc] but it is definitely not good programming style." That was my case. Answer accepted.

Comment: @toupper: It's worth mentioning that if you want a shorter syntax, you can do `[myClass new];` which is equivalent to `[[myClass alloc] init];`, but it could hardly be considered to be in vogue.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is not a good idea.
Read Cocoa Design Pattern, especially the "Two stage creation"

You can also read this article http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398610

Comment: I don't totally get the point "Cocoa Design Pattern - Two stage creation" made: it claims two stage creation is better because it avoids explosion of "constructors / class methods / factory methods", but comparing to java, doesn't [[Foo alloc] init] same as Foo f = new Foo(); f.init();?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it wouldn't matter much if you didn't implement a "- (id)init"  because if you did, you would call NSObject's init method which just returns the same value you send to the method.  Though it is a good idea to create your own init method to set your instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

in runtime source code
perform `-(id)init` will call `_objc_rootInit(self)` and will return `self`. I guess only perform init is OK。