# initWithWindow: in window controller not get called

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm new to Cocoa programming.

In Xcode 6.1 I created an OS X app using storyboard. There's a Window Controller in the Outline out of the box. I changed its class in the "Identity Inspector" to a customized subclass of `NSWindowController`, which is named `WindowController`.

I wrote the following code in the `@implementation` of `WindowController`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *) window {
    NSLog(@"window");
    window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;
    return [super initWithWindow:window];
}
```

But the Output panel shows nothing.

if I override the `windowDidLoad` method in the class,

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    self.window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;
    NSLog("@Cool...");
}
```

The message shows up.

The [doc of `NSWindowController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/) says that `-initWithWindow:` is the Designated Initiailzer of the class. How can it be skipped?

In the [How Window Controllers Work section of Window Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingWindowController.html), it says:

> For simple documents—that is, documents with only one nib file containing a window—you need do little directly with `NSWindowController` objects. AppKit creates one for you. However, if the default window controller is not sufficient, you can create a custom subclass of `NSWindowController`.

That's exactly what I am doing. But I don't know what I'm missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: might have to do with usage of storyboards, how do you setup/instantiate the window controller? Only within storyboard or from code?

Comment: Hi, @Volker. Thank you for your reply. I just use the storyboard. I don't understand why `initWithWindow:` has been bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should first call super with initWithWindow and then set the title. Otherwise the call to super initializes the window without the previous settings.
When you override the windowDidLoad method, you set the title visibility after initialization and everything is okay.

Comment: Thank you:-) But the `NSLog` added in `initWithWindow:` doesn't take effect. Is that indicating `initWithWindow:` is skipped? I guess there's some magic going on here. If it is skipped here, does it mean we should not override `initWithWindow:` and should write initialization code in `windowDidLoad`? And I just read [Would it be correct/ellegant use only alloc without init?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085968/would-it-be-correct-ellegant-use-only-alloc-without-init) and thought it shouldn't be skipped.